# What are the Shrines used for?

Tags: child-of-light

On occasion I come across shrines where Aurora would say

> What a curious Shrine, perhaps one day it was a sign.

I have gotten the Moon however she still says the same thing. Are the shrines used for anything? If so when?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are used in one side-quest `The Lost Lights` where the goal was to find six fireflies across through-out the world.

Besides that, there is no other use for shrines.

[Source](http://www.ign.com/wikis/child-of-light/The_Lost_Lights)